# How to get basic Visual Studio features for javascript (VS 2010)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, refactoring, intellisense

I'm looking for a good way to add a couple capabilities to VS 2010's javascript intellisense that are working properly for C#. Specifically, I want to:

- reliably refactor javascript code
- go to the function definition (`F12` for me) and
- check for all uses of a function or item (`Shift` + `F12` for me).

I'm aware of [Refactor!](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Refactoring/) and [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/default.asp), but I haven't found any comment on how well the features they advertise are supported in javascript. Most of the features they advertise seem to be based on languages that are much less dynamic.

So, I ask:

1. Any comment on the plugins mentioned above?
2. Are there any other good plugins that add these features (or most of them) to VS 2010?
3. Are there any IDE's that approach this feature set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ReSharper 6](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) has great support for JavaScript.

It does include features like:

- Refactoring (it's not 100% reliable since it's not possible with JavaScript, but it's *really* good at it)
- Go to definition
- Find usages

On the downside, it's a little expensive; but, as far as I'm concerned, it's worth the price.